# How to set application wide settings for Go apps in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The Google App engine for Go does not accept environment variables via the `app.yaml` file. How do you setup application wide settings without using the environment?

---

In my specific case I have a watcher type webhook app (https://github.com/jjasonclark/pulltabs) that needs to handle HMAC decryption. So I need to have a secret code for this to work.  I would like to deploy many copies with different secret settings, aka not hard coded. Normally this would be an environment variable settings.

Comment: Normally you put "secret codes" in environment variables?? The same environment space that on many/most OSes is readable by any process??

Comment: Don't just post snark @DaveC, post your solution. We want to learn and upvote. If your solution is "don't do this and instead do ..." then thats great! This question could help us find the right question to be asking based on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some approaches that may suit depending on your needs:

- Config file
- Datastore

**Config file**
Add a config file to your project and load the settings from there on app initialization. [Beegae](https://github.com/astaxie/beegae/blob/master/config.go) is an example of that approach.  Depending on your security needs you might choose to exclude the file from git, create/update it during your deployment process or even consider multiple config files for different cases.

**Datastore**
Store the settings in the datastore and load them on application initialization.  This may be useful if settings need to be changed without redeploying the application each time, or multiple applications share the same datastore and some look-up logic for settings makes sense.